# Populate data from firestore collection

Tags: reactjs, google-cloud-firestore

I've written the function to retrieve data from firestore collection, when I console log the list, I can see all the documents in the "users" collection, the issue I'm facing currently is that the data is not displaying on the form which I want to update... I've set the value for all the inputs to retrieve the data, yet it's not showing on the form but I can see all the documents in the "users" collection in my console log..

Here's the code:-

```js
const initialState = {
  regNo: "",
  firstName: "",
  lastName: "",
  email: "",
  reffBy: "",
  phoneNumber: "",
  age: "",
  date: "",
  status: "",
};

const New = ({title}) => {


  const [file, setFile] = useState("");
  const [data, setData] = useState({});
  const [userInfo, setUserInfo] = useState(initialState);
  const navigate = useNavigate();


  //fetch the id for each doc in a collection
  const {id} = useParams();

  const { regNo, firstName, lastName, email, reffBy, phoneNumber,  age, date, status}= userInfo;

// fetch ID from the collection
  useEffect(() =>{
    //This runs only when there's an ID
    const unsub = onSnapshot(
      collection(db, "users"),
      (snapShot) => {
        let list = [];
        snapShot.docs.forEach((doc) => {
          list.push({ id: doc.id, ...doc.data() });
        });
        setData(list);
        console.log(list)
      },
      (error) => {
        console.log(error);
      }
    );
    
    return () => {
      unsub();
    };
    }, [id]);

// For updating userInput
    useEffect(()=>{
      // This runs when there's an ID and Data
      if (id) {
        setUserInfo({...data[id]});
      } else {
        setUserInfo({...initialState});
      }

      return () =>{
        setUserInfo({...initialState});
      }
    }, [id, data])



    const handleInput = (e) => {
      const {name, value} = e.target;
      setUserInfo({...userInfo, [name]: value});
    }

 

  const handleAdd = async(e) => {
      e.preventDefault();
      
      await addDoc(collection(db, "users"), {
        ...userInfo,
        timeStamp: serverTimestamp(),
      });
      navigate("/")
  }

  return (
    <div className='new'>
    <Sidebar/>
    <div className="newContainer">
    <Navbar/>
    <div className="top">
    <h1> {title} </h1>
    </div>
    <div className="bottom">
    <div className="left">
      <img src={file ? URL.createObjectURL(file): "https://icon-library.com/images/no-image-icon/no-image-icon-0.jpg"} alt=''/>
    </div>
    <div className="right">
    
    <form onSubmit={handleAdd}>
              <div className="formInput">
                <label htmlFor="file">
                  Image: <DriveFolderUploadIcon className="icon" />
                </label>
                <input
                  type="file"
                  id="file"
                  onChange={(e) => setFile(e.target.files[0])}
                  style={{ display: "none" }}
                />
              </div>

              <div className="formInput">
                <label>ID</label>
                <input 
                id="regNo"
                name="regNo"
                type="text" 
                required
                placeholder="enter client id"
                value={regNo || ""}
                onChange={handleInput}
                />
              </div>


              <div className="formInput">
                <label>First Name</label>
                <input 
                id="firstName"
                name="firstName"
                type="text" 
                required
                placeholder="enter first name"
                value={firstName || ""}
                onChange={handleInput}
                />
              </div>


              <div className="formInput">
                <label>Last Name</label>
                <input 
                id="lastName"
                name="lastName"
                type="text" 
                required
                placeholder="enter last name"
                value={lastName || ""}
                onChange={handleInput}
                />
              </div>


              <div className="formInput">
                <label>Email</label>
                <input 
                id="email"
                name="email"
                type="email" 
                required
                placeholder="enter your email address"
                value={email || ""}
                onChange={handleInput}
                />
              </div>

              <div className="formInput">
                <label>Refferal</label>
                <input 
                id="reffBy"
                name="reffBy"
                type="text" 
                required
                placeholder="enter your referral"
                value={reffBy || ""}
                onChange={handleInput}
                />
              </div>

              <div className="formInput">
                <label>Phone Number</label>
                <input 
                id="phoneNumber"
                name="phoneNumber"
                type="number" 
                required
                placeholder="phone number"
                value={phoneNumber || ""}
                onChange={handleInput}
                />
              </div>

              <div className="formInput">
                <label>Age</label>
                <input 
                id="age"
                name="age"
                type="text" 
                required
                placeholder="age"
                value={age || ""}
                onChange={handleInput}
                />
              </div>

              <div className="formInput">
                <label>Date</label>
                <input 
                id="date"
                name="date"
                type="date" 
                required
                value={date || ""}
                onChange={handleInput}
                />
              </div>

              <div className="formInput">
                <label>Status</label>
                <input 
                id="status"
                name="status"
                type="text" 
                required
                placeholder="status"
                value={status || ""}
                onChange={handleInput}
                />
              </div>
             <button
             type="submit"
             >
              Send
             </button>
            </form>

    </div>
    </div>
    </div>
    </div>
  )
}
```

Please what exactly is the issue why I'm not see the data on the form?

Answer (score 1):

The code in your second `useEffect()` is assuming that `data` already has a value.  But if the first `useEffect()`'s asynchronous action has not completed (and it almost certainly won't have) before the second useEffect runs, you'll get no data into the `userInfo` variable.

Your attempt to call `setUserInfo()` is dependent on the successful completion of the fetching of the "users" collection.  So why not simply put the call to `setUserInfo()` INSIDE the callback function of `onSnapshot()` ?

BTW: I'm not sure that you need to be querying all of the "users" collection, do you?  Don't you just need the ONE document for the user with the UID of `id` ??

Also, I am not a fan of mixing "state variables" and "regular JS variables" as being done in the line:

```js
const { regNo, firstName, lastName, email, reffBy, phoneNumber,  age, date, status}= userInfo;
```

Instead, consider accessing each field with:

```js
userInfo["regNo"]
```

or

```js
userInfo.regNo
```